# Error with JS.ERB file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new into Rails world, and I'm trying to learn.
I'm following these tutorial: http://www.noupe.com/development/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html and trying to create an simple twitter application.
All code can be found in https://github.com/ricardovsilva/twitter-rubyOnRails .

I'm trying to add some ajax and javascript functionallity to my app and I'm having a lot of issues (and some of they I'm able to deal with google searchs) because tutorial is in rails 2 and I'm using rails 4.

The line of tutorial I'm stucked is:

> Finally, we need to create the rjs template. To do this, create a file called “create.js.rjs” in the views/posts folder and add the following code.
>
> page.insert_html :top, :posts, :partial => @post
>
> page[@post].visual_effect :highlight

The problem is, when my browser try to render the page that uses this JS, I get the following error :  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

By the way, I'm using google chrome. To simulate the error just clone the repo, access this and run rails server. Open browser and go to http://localhost:3000/posts . Page will render, but with one error (posts will not be loaded, only one textbox and one button).

I really don't know what to do to make the browser understand these rails commands.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: This is all that appears on my terminal

> => Booting WEBrick
>
> => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
>
> => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>
> => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>
> [2015-02-28 15:01:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
>
> [2015-02-28 15:01:33] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x64-mingw32]
>
> [2015-02-28 15:01:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5872 port=3000
>
> Started GET "/posts" for ::1 at 2015-02-28 15:01:39 -0300
>
> ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM
>   `schema_migrations`
>
> Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
>
> Rendered posts/_message_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
>
> Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`  ORDER BY `posts`.`created_at`
>    ASC
>
> Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (13.0ms)
>
> Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/posts (52.0ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 120ms (Views: 78.0ms | ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/create-3acb657a1c6a2ce4ccc5172e5bd59c6e.js?body=1" for ::1
>
> at 2015-02-28 15:01:41 -0300

The file where error happens is the create.js.erb, that is saved into folder app/assets/javascript.
This is the content of file:

```
page.insert_html :top, :posts, :partial => @posts
page[@post].visual_effect : highlight
```

[Edit 2 - After @rubykid suggestion]
I'm calling these javascript (or trying) from the posts.html.erb, but now I'm having error on console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <%=javascript_include_tag :all%>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's appear like he's trying to get the "all.js" file, and he will not, because it's don't exists. (on terminal I get this line **Started GET "/javascripts/all.js" for ::1 at 2015-02-28 15:44:04 -0300**)
What is the correct syntax in ruby 4?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you post the code in here rather than making us look at a github page. Can we please see the code in the template?

Comment: Also, that tutorial is from 2009. A LOT has changed in Rails since then (and Ruby has gone through no fewer than four major releases), and you're likely to get a lot of errors. It's going to be really painful. If you're trying to build a Rails 2 app in Rails 4, you're going to be pulling your hair out.

Comment: I can put a code here, but Rails have a lot of files and code is splitted. I don't know well what piece of code put here. This is why I pointed to github folder. When you says code of Template, of wich file are you talking about? (and sorry for this ask, as I said, I'm new with rails and I'm don't understanding everything yet)

Comment: As @nickcoxdotme mention it's really painfull, as you novice it will be better to find tutorial adapted for Rails 4.

Comment: Yeah, the very first file in the stack trace. That `SyntaxError` should show you the call stack. It'll give you a filename and line number. Can you show us the file that that line number occurs in?

Comment: I get the SyntaxError from google chrome, when I open the inspector. I edited the answer and included the terminal stack.

Comment: Added the content of file with error too

Comment: @RicardoSilva first of all move it to views/posts folder as described in your tutor

Comment: second, create.js.erb - simple js file wrapped up in erb so you can use ruby variables and helpers here, for example you can use @posts local variable, but syntax will be different as for Rails 2 rjs templates. I think first line (`page.insert_html :top, :posts, :partial => @posts`) might look like next: `$('.posts').append("<%= j render 'posts', posts: @posts %>" )`

Comment: @rubykid , I moved the file to folder you said. I didn't understand well what you said. Now I have to create one file create.js.erb into javascript folder too?

Comment: You need to rewrite this file. And move it out from the assets/javascript/folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71957/discussion-between-rubykid-and-ricardo-silva).

Comment: In general it's best to avoid templated JS. I'd strongly consider following an up to date tutorial as Rails 2 is far, far behind the curve at this point.